# Use hibernate Criteria to search all occurencies from a sub-class that has same attribute name and value

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I have `A` class, and `B`,`C`,`D`,`E`,`F`,`G`,`H`,`I` are all sub-classes from `A`. `C`, `F`, `I` have an attribute named `value`. How do I create a Criteria query to search all `C`, `F`, `I` that have `value` = 25?

Here's a sample code that I built:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("aliasA.value", 25));
```

But when I check the SQL generated it only has a reference to `C` entity. How do I tell hibernate that it needs to search all sub-classes?

Comment: create a `MappedSuperClass` of all C,F,I classes and query that class

Comment: Do you mean another class, besides A? But I can,t, cause I need to search fields from A class too

Comment: yes it will extend A but all C,F,I will extend this class. search for MappedSuperClass